# Pass data to file_get_contents() in PHP

Tags: php, echo, file-get-contents

I'm having some problems doing this:

I have to make some reports which display like this:

[image]

As you can see, the **.php** receive by url the id of user (`idusuario=14`).

Now, i have another **.php** with this code:

```
<?php

    $idusuario = 14;

    $postdata = http_build_query(
        array(
            'idusuario' => $idusuario
        )
    );

    $opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'  => 'GET',
            'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'content' => $postdata
        )
    );

    $context  = stream_context_create($opts);

    $result = file_get_contents('ContentEnvio.php', false, $context );

    echo $result;

?>
```

When i `echo $result`, shoul display like the image above or not ?

The result is this:

[image]

Comment: `file_get_contents` does what it says.  Gets the contents of the file as a string.  You probably wanted to `include 'ContentEnvio.php';`.

Comment: It should display the contents like the 2nd image, as the PHP isn't interpreted, just the contents of the php file grabbed locally. Can't you just `include` it (and see you get some other mechanism the a hardcoded `$_GET` to get your parameters from. Usually, a function or class that can be fed a variable (which may or may not come from a `$_GET` or `$argv` array, or even defined in the spot) instead of a file which examines some variables makes code more versatile.

Comment: its because you are loading the file locally ... make it this ` $result = file_get_contents('http://http://localhost/appslovers/test/ContentEnvio.php', false, $context );` or what ever with the full path

Comment: For now, setting `$_GET['idusuario'] = 14; include 'ContentEnvio.php';` would probably work, but altering the `$_GET` is frowned upon, and should only every be a _temporary_ fix.

Comment: @ChristopherMorrissey: that code assumes a lot about the local server configuration (that the servername `localhost` goes to this website for instance)... At the very least use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, but even that may fail in some network setups (multiple servers behind loadbalancers with no clear route to the external IP for instance). If we're already there, avoiding a subrequest over HTTP is preferably, because is would mean a lot of work to make that reliably portable, if at all.

Comment: I got it !! Thank you everyone for comments.... But, How can i set the result in a variable? Is it possible?

Comment: @JhonatanSandoval: for the `include` solution, you can use `ob_start()` before the code, and use `$result=ob_get_clean()` after the code, but Ideally you'd have a function/method that returns strings, so you can _decide_ whether you want to `echo` it or do something else with it, rather then having that decision forced upon you. Another code-versatility thingy :P